# How to insert text to an existing text in a cell if the cell next to it has this text?

Tags: jquery

I have an existing table with rows like this:

```
<tr class="ds-table-row even">
<td class="label-cell">dc.date.updated</td>
<td class="value-cell">2012-06-13T11:28:48Z</td>
</tr>

<tr class="ds-table-row odd">
<td class="label-cell">DOI</td>
<td class="value-cell">10.1007/s10811-010-9649-9</td>
</tr>

<tr class="ds-table-row even">
<td class="label-cell">Volume</td>
<td class="value-cell">23</td>
</tr>
```

Is it possible using jquery to insert http://dx.doi.org/ to the cell next to it if its value = DOI? In my example, I would like to make `10.1007/s10811-010-9649-9` into `http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10811-010-9649-9`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target all `.label-cell` elements that contain `DOI` (for exact match you could use a filter instead), get the next `TD` and change the text by prepending the string `http://dx.doi.org/` to the existing text :

```
$('.label-cell:contains(DOI)').next('td').text(function(_,txt) {
    return 'http://dx.doi.org/' + txt;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/P847S/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.append()` to each TD if string equals "DOI"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('td').each(function(index, value) {
    var td = $(this);
    if (td.html() == 'DOI') {
        var next = td.next();
        next.html('http://dx.doi.org/' + next.html().split('/')[0]);
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/pp7fT/)**